# Unknown escape sequence '\x20'

Tags: ios, sql-server, ios4

I've created this code

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Update Expense_Group set Expense_sum = Expense_sum-\%@\ where Expense_Type_Id = \"%@\"",strExpAmount,current_Expense_TypeId];
```

and now,i got this warning "**Unknown escape sequence '\x20'**".

Answer (score 1):

You only need to "`\`" escape the quotes within that "`stringWithFormat:`" call...

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Update Expense_Group set Expense_sum = Expense_sum-%@ where Expense_Type_Id = %@",strExpAmount,current_Expense_TypeId];
```

This may solve the issue no need of escape sequence before %@.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Update Expense_Group set Expense_sum = Expense_sum-'%@' where Expense_Type_Id = '%@'",strExpAmount,current_Expense_TypeId];
```